# Pgfplot display only x axis, one value point with label and text

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot a chart with one axis and draw a point at a specific value and show it with a label. In addition I'd like to place two label on the min and max tick of x axis. For q better understanding see the image:

[image: Wanted plot]

EDIT: If it possible I'd like also to hide the axis itself, show only ticks with the values and the points with the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tikz` can do this:

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,5}{
    \draw (\x,0.2) -- (\x,-0.2)node[below]{\x};
    }
    \draw[fill=magenta!40] (3.5,0) circle (3pt)node[above=0.2cm,anchor=south]{3.5};
    \node[anchor=north] at (0,-0.6) {Start};
    \node[anchor=north] at (5,-0.6) {End};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that is what I needed